# How to Mask / Drop a JSON column using kafka connect Transforms

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using a Kafka debizium MySQL connector, I am trying to drop / mask a json column using transforms,

tried mask field but its not working

```
transforms: "maskField",
transforms.maskField.type: "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value",
transforms.maskField.fields: "data",
```

```
original :

{
  "id": "10001",
  "data": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}

expected :

{
  "id": "10001",
  "data": null
}

or 

{
  "id": "10001"
}
```

How can I achieve this, using transforms ??

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? As written in the documentation, mask field transform is only for numeric or string data. You have an object/map, which won't work, and there's no existing transform that really work well with nested data formats except for Extract/Hoist

Comment: no error, and also I am not seeing any transformation too, but yes thats what I thought, Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

There is also this way:

> "transforms": "ReplaceField",
>
> "transforms.ReplaceField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
>
> "transforms.ReplaceField.blacklist": "field_name_here"

I am not %100 sure but you may give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a kafka connect [mask-json-field](https://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2023/06/mask-json-field-transform-kafka-connect.html) SMT, that can mask out fields from a JSON message in a kafka topic.

It supports both messages with schema, and without.

Give it a try and see.